# Calculating spot rate of interest

Tags: spot-rate

You are given the following information regarding the domestic government fixed-interest bond market:

- The current price of a **one-year bond** paying coupons at a rate of $4.5$% per annum and redeemed at par is £100.41 per £100 nominal
- The current price of a **two-year bond** paying coupons at a rate of $6.5$% per annum and redeemed at par is £100.48 per £100 nominal

Calculate the two-year spot rate of interest, $y_2$

I'm not sure how to start this question. Do we have to work out the first and second year forward rates?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? You posted a [similar plea on Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/348422/24951).

Comment: It's a practice question in one of the tutorial sheets, not a homework assignment. They have only given the answer of the question but I do not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving for annual interest rates:

The one year annual spot rate r1:
$$ 
   1.045/(1+r1)=1.0041 => r1 \approx 4.0733\%
$$
The one-two year forward rate r1,2: 
$$
.065/(1+r1)+1.065/(1+r1)(1+r1,2)=1.0048 => r1,2 \approx 8.5927\%
$$
The two year spot rate r2=
$$
(1+r2)^{2}=(1+r1)(1+r1,2) => r2 \approx 6.3090\%
$$